# What is the best way to catch "Operation cancelled by user" exception

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have the following piece of code:

```
IAsyncResult beginExecuteReader = command.BeginExecuteNonQuery();

while (!beginExecuteReader.IsCompleted)
{
    if (controllerTask.CancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        command.Cancel();
    }

    Thread.Sleep(100);
}

try
{
    result = command.EndExecuteNonQuery(beginExecuteReader);
}
catch (SqlException exception)
{
    if (exception.ErrorCode == OperationCanceled)
    {
        throw new OperationCanceledException();
    }
    
    throw;
}
```

How can I identify that the exception caught was caused by operation cancelation?

In this case `ExecuteNonQuery` throws an exception with error code `0x80131904`, but it's a very general exception which can be caused by many reasons. The error message looks like this: "A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.\r\nOperation cancelled by user."

I don't see any options except parsing the error message... Any ideas?

Thanks

PS. Yeah, I know that using the `Cancel` command for async operation probably is not the best idea, because in the .NET 2.0 documentation on MSDN there was a warning. But in the .NET 4.0 documentation, this warning is removed.
I also don't like other implementations where the cancel method is called from another thread, as for me it makes code more difficult.

Comment: No, this is just a class library, which works with database via ADO.NET classes (.NET 4.0). So i can't use BackgroundWorker :)

Comment: Ok, you will use ur library in winforms? Or where?

Comment: It can be used everywhere. For now it's used by Windows service, WCF service, WPF application, Console application)

Comment: The live-lock can be replaced with myCancelToken.Register(() => cmd.Cancel()); and then you can just call the blocking ExecuteNonQuery instead of BeginExecuteNonQuery. When the token is being cancelled, the ExecuteNonQuery will throw an sqlException

Answer (score 9):

There doesn't seem to be a locale insensitive mechanism to catch just this error.  The [HResult 0x80131904 is just `COR_E_SqlException`](https://www.magnumdb.com/search?q=0x80131904). The error is initiated at [TdsParser.cs:2332](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs,2332) without any unique properties.  It is almost the exact same code as [:2759 - Unknown Error](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs,2759) and [:3850 - Unexpected Collation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/System/Data/SqlClient/TdsParser.cs,3850).

Here are the bad solutions I have come up with:

**Option 1:** Break the good advice of "don't make logic locale sensitive"

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);Integrated Security=True;"))
{
    con.Open();

    try
    {
        var sqc = new SqlCommand("WAITFOR DELAY '1:00:00'", con);
        var readThread = Task.Run(() => sqc.ExecuteNonQuery());

        // cancel after 5 seconds
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        sqc.Cancel();

        // this should throw
        await readThread;

        // unreachable
        Console.WriteLine("Succeeded");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == 0 && ex.State == 0 && ex.Class == 11 
        && ex.Message.Contains("Operation cancelled by user."))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** Assume that no other severe locally generated error matters after a cancel has been issued

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Server=(local);Integrated Security=True;"))
{
    con.Open();

    bool isCancelled = false;
    try
    {
        var sqc = new SqlCommand("WAITFOR DELAY '1:00:00'", con);
        var readThread = Task.Run(() => sqc.ExecuteNonQuery());

        // cancel after 5 seconds
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        isCancelled = true;
        sqc.Cancel();

        // this should throw
        await readThread;

        // unreachable
        Console.WriteLine("Succeeded");
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) when (isCancelled && ex.Number == 0 && ex.State == 0 && ex.Class == 11)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Cancelled");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: I like the option 2!

Answer (score -3):

So imho you should to do next:

1. Make a thread where you will use ado (read this [Thread example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread%28v=vs.71%29.aspx))
2. Delete Thread.Sleep(100); //Imho never use it
3. Add to your class static bool muststop=false;
4. Add to your class public static function to change "muststop"
5. Change you thread's function to stop it if muststop==true

I hope this help you

Answer (score -4):

You can exam exception message in catch block to find which operation was cancelled by user:

```
try
{
   //your code
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
  if (ex.Message.Contain("Operation cancelled by user"))
   {
       //Do something here
   }
}
```